# Derived column add conditional column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I will like to add a column to an existing table using a derived column. Is this possible?

However the new column `N` will be conditional. For example, when `column A = 1` and `column B <> 2` then it's value will be `1` and when `Column A = 2` and `Column B = 1` then `2`. When `column A = 3` then the value is `0`, otherwise `4`.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive the column but to insert it into a table it should already exist in that target table. So the short answer is no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Test set N = 
    case
        when A = 1 and B != 2 then 1
        when A = 2 and B  = 2 then 2
        when A = 3 then 0
        else 4
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **? :** construction in a Derived Column to create a conditionally filled column:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx